# Why is dynamical selection of column & table names so difficult in SQL?

Tags: sql, language-design

I figure there has to be a specific design reason why you can't write a query like the following one:

```
select 
    (select column_name 
    from information_schema 
    where column_name not like '%rate%' 
    and table_name = 'Fixed_Income')
from Fixed_Income
```

and instead have to resort to dynamic SQL.

Anyone knows what that reason is? I tried Googling it, but all the hits were cries for help in solving the problem -- meaning it's a pretty widespread need and not well understood.

Comment: What database are you talking about? What types are `column_name` and `table_name`?

Comment: It's a general SQL design question. I don't think any database allows this.

Comment: In your example, you make it dynamic by saying "I want all but %rate%". Like @usr said, it is not possible through the static sql engine and to do so you have to use the adequate tools i.e. dynamic execution tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask a very interesting question.

The "relational" in "relational algebra" refers to name-value pairs, not to relationships between tables.  In relational algebra, there is no requirement that all records in a set (table) have the same columns.

My best guess is that the limitation is related to the idea of entity-relationship diagrams comes into play.  A database is designed around tables, and these tables have relationships to each other.  The choice of a relational database for data storage and access was specifically when the data could be stored this way.  Knowing the entities and their attributes suggests a static form of the data and hence static references in queries.

In addition, SQL as a language is a *declarative* language rather than a *procedural* language.  This suggests -- but does not impose -- a compilation step separate from the running of the query.  In general, the SQL engine does the following (at a very high level):

1. Compiles the query, generally into some sort of data flow process.
2. Optimizes the data flow process.  (Typically part of the compilation process.)
3. Runs the query.

The first two result in what is called "the query plan".  You really cannot do optimization, though, unless you know about the objects you are operating on.  So, dynamically choosing tables and columns means that optimization would be part of running the query rather than compiling it.

Finally, some databases like SQL Server support dynamic SQL.  This allows you to build strings that get compiled and run at the same time.  This is very useful for complex decision support queries.  It is not recommended when you need fast transaction throughput, because the overhead for compilation is too high relative to the query.

Comment: I think I get it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's like trying to write code to print all variables whose names start with 'rate'.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that the query optimizer needs to know the exact schema objects you are referring to at compile time. It needs them to optimize the query. You wouldn't believe how slow the RDBMS would be without having this information available to the query optimizer.

It's a little like the performance difference of static vs. dynamic typing in practice: There is usually a non-trivial difference (I'm thinking just about mainstream languages here). The compiler can exploit the static information to generate great code.

Even if this feature was present, it would be implemented by first computing the table and column names and then doing a standard "static" query planning.

Comment: Databases are not optimized for the convenience of the developer (really this sort of thing would save less than 5 minutes worth of work) but for the performance of the queries. I've done database work for 30 years and never once have I needed or wanted to do such a thing.

Comment: I can think of a hypothetical reason:  a sort of "ad hoc" query that would allow on-the-fly report building by the end-user.  e.g., select from a list of columns to include on a report that can have up to 8 columns, for example.  But this sort of task is better handled by a report builder anyway.

Comment: Human beings would have never known they don't have a marsupial pocket without the kangaroo ;) Just to say I agree with you but, maybe if we had such a tool we would use it to propose new algorithms.. who knows.